# How to subset your dataframe to keep first 3 duplicate rows in R?

Tags: r, duplicates, distinct

I have a table in the following form

[image]

I want to keep only the first 3 rows based on duplicate values of V1 & V@ like below:

[image]

df %>% distinct(V1,V2) only let me keep the first row.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of data.  Post code to generate your data instead.

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(V1, V2) %>%
  filter(row_number() <= 3)
     V1    V2    V3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     4
2     1     2     5
3     1     2     6
4     9     3    10
5     9     3    15
6     9     3    16
```

Comment: Can also use `slice_head(n=3)` instead of `filter`

Answer (score 0):

With data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(c(rep(1, 4), rep(9, 5)), c(rep(2, 4), rep(3, 5)), c(4:7, 10, 15:18)) 
dt[, .SD[1:3], by = c('V1', 'V2')]
   V1 V2 V3
1:  1  2  4
2:  1  2  5
3:  1  2  6
4:  9  3 10
5:  9  3 15
6:  9  3 16
```

You can use `.SD[1:min(3, .N)]` if you don't want a row with V3 = NA if there are less than 3 duplicates.